# Elasticsearch JDBC driver SQL Error: current license is non-compliant for [jdbc]

Tags: elasticsearch, jdbc, dbeaver

Using DBeaver with an Elasticsearch JDBC driver, I just recently began to encounter the following:

`SQL Error: current license is non-compliant for [jdbc]`

This happens both under Version **22.0.5**.202205220912 (released on May 23rd, 2022) and also under the recent Version **22.3.3**.202301211053 of DBeaver (just released on January 23rd, 2023.)

Is this somehow being caused by the Elasticsearch end-point?

Comment: I don't think this has got anything to do with DBeaver, but with Elasticsearch. This [page](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/current-license-is-non-compliant-for-jdbc/152594) suggests it depends on your Elasticsearch license whether or not you are allowed to connect with JDBC. And refers to [this page](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions) which has an entry "JDBC Client". It seems only Platinum and Enterprise subscriptions allow use of JDBC.

Comment: The comment by @MarkRotteveel is likely the correct answer.  We were using an old "Community Edition" of ES 6.8 and recently upgraded.  That change to the end-point seems to have removed the free support for JDBC that we had enjoyed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using the [JDBC Client for Elastic search](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/jdbc-client) which needs a platinum ([or trail](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/current-license-is-non-compliant-for-jdbc/152594)) license. Maybe your trial has expired?

For more details, you can always look at [elastic.co/subscriptions](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions) (screenshot below) which clearly explains what feature is included and what is not!

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35380152)